# Clarify the FAQ's use of software tools

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, faq-update-request

I think the FAQ should be changed from:

> software tools commonly used by programmers

To a clearer:

> the use of software tools commonly used by programmers

Or:

> a specific software tool commonly used by programmers

The first promotes shopping questions, while the second does not. Thoughts?

Comment: I tend to agree in principle, but can't really see this making any significant impact on the rate at which shopping questions appear.

Comment: @mac - a step in the right direction

Comment: @Mac, it'll make it clearer on which questions should be cleaned up though.

Comment: While we're at it, we should also clarify that it means "software tools related to programming", not "software tools commonly used by many people (including programmers)".

Comment: Not sure this would curtail shopping questions - I think the benefit here would be easier clarification when they're closed. That said, the FAQ is soon to be quite different - I'll share your suggestion with Laura today. Not posting an answer as this _may_ be a completely moot point by the time she's done.

Comment: @Mac: Or the rate at which people vote to close legitimate questions about the use of programming tools.

Comment: Well, the primary point of the FAQ is a reference anyway. Those who consistently post bad questions probably haven't read it to begin with. It's more of an authoritative community reference.